# Google App Engine OAuth 1.0a Application-Only

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am using Google App Engine with it's default [OAuth Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview). I can easily access it with the help of [Google OAuth Java Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) - I get the request token, user authorizes and everything work just fine.

My question is - is there a way to access my API without user context? So called `application-only` method (see [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)) (in OAuth2 it's called `client_credentials`?

Because some of my API methods (on my personal Google App Engine application) really don't need any user context - just a consumer key so I can identify and measure my API consumers.